# How to ensure that Polygon[list] plots a simple polygon?

Tags: graphics, programming, computational-geometry

Consider the following code which plots a triangle.

```
 p = {{0, 0}, {.2, 0}, {0, .2}};
 {Cyan, Polygon[Dynamic[p]]} // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then adding (for example) `{.1, -.1}` yields a non-simple polygon with  intersecting lines.

```
AppendTo[p, {.1, -.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**: Given a list of 2D points that are plotted as a polygon by `Graphics`. Is there a way to re-order the points such that `Graphics` plots a [simple polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) after a point which has been added that resulted in plotting a non-simple polygon?

Comment: to understand better what you want, suppose I had `p = {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {0, 0}}`; what polygon should be plotted?

Comment: p1 = {-1, 1};
p2 = {1, 1};
p3 = {-1, -1};
p4 = {1, -1};
p5 = {0, 0};
p = {p1, p2, p4, p3, p5} would pass.

Comment: That one is not convex by the way. I have been using the wrong words I realized. I don't want the ones which look like connected via a single point. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Sort of, but I think it is ambiguous. Would the convex hull work? It might not include all the points

Comment: Thanks, @acl. Yes, it is ambiguous, I know. Think of a polygon and clicking 'somewhere' adds a point to the polygon with the ability to move it to the spot where you want it. Now, sometimes Polygon plots unexpected polygons from a list of points. That's what I am trying to ' fix '.

Comment: I'll have to look into the ConvexHull package stuff.

Comment: @ndroock1: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to minimize self-intersections? Would `FindShortestTour` work?

Comment: so, is this a correct way to express what you want: given a list of points, arrange them so that `Polygon` does not produce a polygon which can be cut in two by removing a single point

Comment: @ndroock1 Polygon doesn't plot unexpected polygons, it plots exactly what you tell it to plot. The order of the points matters however as you have learned. There isn't one particular "correct" order of traversing a number of points to form a polygon, so while you can find a different order which doesn't contain intersecting lines it may not be the one you where actually expecting. I suggest posting your full problem, since I suspect you could avoid this problem completely by always inserting a new point ordered in between the two nearest already present points, rather then prepending.

Comment: Also, now that you know that "convex" polygon is wrong terminology, you should update your question so that others aren't misled by your incorrect question.

Comment: Some more possible solutions are given in the duplicate question [Rebuild a polygon so it doesn't self intersect](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48091/484).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you may be looking for is `FindCurvePath`. Its task is to find reasonable curves through disorganized point sets. It is not guaranteed to find the solution that you find most pleasing but if often gets close. You may also end up with several disconnected lines instead of a single one.

```
(* some points randomly drawn on a sine shape *)
pts = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, 30];

Graphics@Line@pts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* now with FindCurvePath *)
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[pts, Line@FindCurvePath@pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the case of your point set it finds the following:

```
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[p, {EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@FindCurvePath@p}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e., a polygon and a line.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean a [convex hull](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexHull.html)? This is always a convex polygon, but in general, not every point in the list will be a vertex of the convex hull.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
Graphics[Polygon[p[[ConvexHull[p]]]]]
```

Comment: Convex is not the right word, I just found out. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming from your explanation that you aren't actually just interested in the convex hull, but simply inserting points into a polygon without creating self-intersecting lines. In this case, you can simply find the closest point and insert either before or after this, depending on which of the neighboring points are closest to the new point.

```
 insertIntoClosestEdge[line_, p_] := 
 Module[{closest, neighbors, nearclosest},
 closest = Nearest[line -> Automatic, p][[1]];
 neighbors = closest // Mod[# + {1, -1}, Length@line, 1] &;
 nearclosest = Nearest[line[[neighbors]] -> neighbors, {.1, -.1}][[1]];
 Insert[line, p, {Mod[closest - If[nearclosest < closest, 0, -1], Length@line]}]
 ]
```

It may need extending to work in all cases, but it shows the gist of the suggested solution.

Answer (score 4):

*The original algorithm is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32785/4678). I post the slightly revised version since it perfectly fits the question.*

### The "deintersection" algorithm

Let us start from some random polygon with $n$ randomly placed vertices. Initially, it has a lot of self-intersections

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 10;
p = RandomReal[1.0, {n, 2}];

Graphics[{Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm@Red, 
  Polygon[p]}]
```

[image]

We want to change the order of these points to get rid of the intersections.

Line segments $(p_1,p_2)$ and $(p_3,p_4)$ intersect if and only if the signs of areas of triangles $p_1p_2p_3$ and $p_1p_2p_4$ are different and the signs of areas of triangles $p_3p_4p_1$ and $p_3p_4p_1$ are also different.

[image]

Corresponding function

```
SignedArea[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  0.5 (#1[[2]] #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] #2[[2]]) &[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
IntersectionQ[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
  SignedArea[p1, p2, p3] SignedArea[p1, p2, p4] < 0 && 
   SignedArea[p3, p4, p1] SignedArea[p3, p4, p2] < 0;
```

The main step:

[image]

Patterns in *Mathematica* are very convenient for searching and removing intersections.

```
Deintersect[p_] := 
  Append[p, p[[1]]] //. 
    {s1___, p1_, p2_, s2___, p3_, p4_, s3___} /; IntersectionQ[p1, p2, p3, p4] :> 
       ({s1, p1, p3, Sequence @@ Reverse@{s2}, p2, p4, s3}) // Most;
```

To add the segment between the last and the first point I use `Append` and `Most`.

As a result we obtain the polygon without intersections

```
p2 = Deintersect[p];
Graphics[{Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm@Red, 
  Polygon[p2]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of V12 we can use [`SimplePolygonQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimplePolygonQ.html):

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 10;
p = RandomReal[1.0, {n, 2}];

Graphics[{Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm@Red, Polygon[p]}]
```

[image]

```
SimplePolygonQ[Polygon[p]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately `SimplePolygonQ` is flawed as of version 13.0.1, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266298/how-to-find-each-internal-angles-of-an-n-sided-irregular-polygon#comment663956_266301).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [195229](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195229/listplot-join-points-by-nearest-neighbor-rather-than-order), the points can be sorted to create a convex polygon. As a demonstration and comparison with `ConvexHullMesh`:

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 10;
pts = RandomReal[1.0, {n, 2}];
m = Mean@pts;
poly = Polygon[SortBy[pts, ArcTan @@ (# - m) &]];
chm = ConvexHullMesh[pts];

GraphicsRow[{
  Graphics[{
    {poly}
    , {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@m}
    , {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point@pts}
    , {Yellow, Dotted, Thin, Line[{m, #}] & /@ pts}
    , {Red, Dashed, MeshPrimitives[chm, 1]}
    , {Text[
      Rotate[#, 12 Degree] &@Style["Convex hull boundary", 14], {0.5, 
       0.9}]}
    , {Text[
      Rotate[#, 46 Degree] &@Style["convex\npolygon", 14], {0.84, 
       0.77}]}
    
    }
   , Axes -> False
   ]
  , Graphics[{
    {FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[White], Polygon@pts}
    , {Red, Dashed, MeshPrimitives[chm, 1]}
    }
   ]
  }]
```

[image]