# Generate a Random Polygon

Tags: random, computational-geometry

Does some package exist with a function that takes a parameter $n$ and generates a random 2D $n$-sided **[simple polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon)** (convex or non-convex), possibly within a certain bounding box?

It does not suffice to simply generate $n$ random points as I would have to figure out how to connect the points in a non-intersecting manner. I am sure there are algorithms to solve this particular problem, but I would much rather use a **ready-made function** that would be guaranteed to work, rather than code my own function and introduce more bugs.

I am trying to generate a large number of "random" test cases for my algorithm that is supposed to work for all polygons.

Comment: Without more information I'd put my money on `RandomReal` or similar. Please add as much info as possible and any relevant code you already have in place.

Comment: as @YvesKlett said, maybe: `Graphics@Polygon[RandomReal[{5, 10}, {RandomInteger[{2, 10}], 2}]]` or similar?

Comment: Generating a random cyclic graph - which is the limit of what `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger` can do - might yield a self-intersecting polygon, which I wish to avoid. I have elaborated on that in my edit to the question.

Comment: Can it have concave angles?

Comment: Yes, that is allowed, and desired. The question did not exclude such a possibility, and "randomness" would definitely produce some concave angles, but let me edit this into the question just to be safe.

Comment: Are the polygons non intersecting with themselves or also against each other?

Comment: One polygon is enough, but if I generate many successively I don't really care whether they intersect each other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is some undocumented functionality in `` Graphics`Mesh `` that may help.

- `SimplePolygonPartition` will break apart a self-intersecting polygon into non-self-intersecting components (the components include the "holes" in the original)
- `PolygonCombine` will merge those components into a single polygon (note that while free of interior holes this polygon may still intersect itself)
- `FindIntersections` will find any self-intersections and can therefore be used to filter out such polygons

.

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

randompoly := Module[{poly},
  While[Length[FindIntersections[
      poly = PolygonCombine @ SimplePolygonPartition @
         Polygon[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}]]]] > 0];
  poly]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, randompoly}]
```

[image]

There are also some built-in polygons which may be useful for testing. They are:

```
PolygonData[]
(* {"Blob", "ChvatalComb", "FractalCross", "HeptaSpiral", "HexaSpiral", 
 "LSystem01", "PentaSpiral", "RandomWalk", "Test01", "TriSpiral"} *)
```

The available properties are:

```
PolygonData["Properties"]
(* {"Data", "Graphics", "GraphicsLine", "GraphicsPoint", 
 "GraphicsPolygon", "Line", "MeshObject", "Point", "Polygon"} *)
```

For example

```
polys = PolygonData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ PolygonData[];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, #}, ImageSize -> 100] & /@ polys
```

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code and it works, but the output of `randompoly` is not a list `poly = {pt1, ..., ptn}` of 2D coordinates, but a graphics primitive `Polygon[poly]`. This hinders manipulation of the output polygon, unless there is a way to "unwrap" the raw data from `Polygon`?

Comment: the output polygons of `randompoly` also seem to have a "fat center" as compared to the output of @ybeltukov's answer. But I see this as a minor issue.

Comment: @HerngYi you can extract the coordinates using `List @@ randompoly`

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find the documentation on the `@@` operator - does it do something like replacing the header of an expression? Would be great if you could link me to some documentation on this.

Comment: @HerngYi Yes, that's exactly what it does.  You can select `@@` in the Front End and press F1 key to bring up the page for [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).  You could also use [this reference](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121) to find the same page.

Answer (score 20):

I propose "deintersection" algorithm.

Let we have $n$ random points.

```
n = 10;
p = RandomReal[1.0, {n, 2}];
```

We want change the order of this points to get rid of the intersections.

Line segments $(p_1,p_2)$ and $(p_3,p_4)$ intersect if and only if the signs of areas of triangles $p_1p_2p_3$ and $p_1p_2p_4$ are different and the signs of areas of triangles $p_3p_4p_1$ and $p_3p_4p_1$ are also different.

[image]

Corresponding function

```
SignedArea[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  0.5 (#1[[2]] #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] #2[[2]]) &[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
IntersectionQ[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
  SignedArea[p1, p2, p3] SignedArea[p1, p2, p4] < 0 && 
   SignedArea[p3, p4, p1] SignedArea[p3, p4, p2] < 0;
```

Main step

[image]

Patterns in *Mathematica* are very convenient for the searching and removing intersections.

```
Deintersect[p_] := 
  Append[p, p[[1]]] //. 
    {s1___, p1_, p2_, s2___, p3_, p4_, s3___} /; IntersectionQ[p1, p2, p3, p4] :> 
       ({s1, p1, p3, Sequence @@ Reverse@{s2}, p2, p4, s3}) // Most;
```

To add the segment between the last and the first point I use `Append` and `Most`.

As a result we got the polygon without intersections

```
p2 = Deintersect[p];
Graphics[{Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm@Red, 
  Polygon[p2]}]
```

[image]

And many other funny polygons

```
Graphics[{Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm@Red, 
      Polygon[#]}, ImageSize -> 100] &@Deintersect[#] & /@ RandomReal[1.0, {10, n, 2}]
```

[image]

As you can see, this algorithm can give more complicated polygons than in other answers.

Comment: This is the same idea I had after reading the question but I wasn't sure how to go about it.  Good thing you're here to implement it for us. :-) +1

Comment: I like the elegance of the implementation using patterns, and the assortment of generated polygons seems more random than that of the other answers, but I was looking for a ready-made function, not a new algorithm. I think that others who ask the same question will be looking for ready-made functions as well, so I did not accept this answer. I will use both this answer and that of @SimonWoods' in my testing, though.

Answer (score 13):

**======= update ===========**

I guess a general method (to get elongated polygons too) would be to sample elliptic shapes of various axis ratios at a few points and then perturb them outwards (inflate) randomly.

```
ngon[n_, s_, r_] := 
 Polygon[RandomReal[r, n] Table[{s Cos[2 Pi k/n], Sin[2 Pi k/n]/s}, {k, n}]]

Table[ngon[RandomInteger[{7, 13}], RandomInteger[{1, 3}], 
    RandomReal[{1, 2}]] // Graphics, {5}, {5}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

**======= older ===========**

Maybe this post is useful to read - there is some sorting points discussion:

[**Character edge finding**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/637/13)

Another idea that does it in a simple way is a perturbative approach. Start from a regular polygon and randomly perturb the vertices. Note it will keep polygons within some bounding box defined by regular polygon side and max perturbation amplitude.

For positive-negative perturbations smaller than some number self-intersections will be impossible. For another positive only perturbations and a different "smaller than number" you will have only convex polygons. The value of these "smaller than numbers" can be found from geometric considerations that I leave to you.

For arbitrary concave and convex shapes define:

```
ngon[n_, r_] := 
 Polygon[Table[RandomReal[{-r, r}, 2] + {Cos[2 Pi k/n], Sin[2 Pi k/n]}, {k, n}]]

Table[Graphics[ngon[RandomInteger[{3, 9}], 
    RandomReal[{.3, .7}]]], {5}, {5}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Here is the limiting case of perturbing a line:

```
n = 7; pts = Table[k/n, {k, -n/2, n/2}];

Table[Join[{RandomReal[{1.1, 1.5}] #, RandomReal[{0, .2}]} & /@ 
      pts, {RandomReal[{1.1, 1.5}] #, RandomReal[{0, -.2}]} & /@ pts //
       Reverse] // Polygon // Graphics, {5}, {5}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

For shapes only convex (with another "less than" parameter):

```
ngon[n_, r_] := 
 Polygon[Table[RandomReal[r, 2] + {Cos[2 Pi k/n], Sin[2 Pi k/n]}, {k, n}]]

Table[Graphics[ngon[RandomInteger[{3, 9}], 
    RandomReal[{.3, .4}]]], {5}, {5}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Comment: Perturbation under a small displacement limit will not be able to produce "thin" polygons such as slightly thickened graphs. I need to test my algorithms on those kinds of polygons as well.

Comment: @HerngYi those can be simulated by perturbing an infinitely thin loop (line) with random shifts outwards from geometrical center.

Comment: @HerngYi I modified the method to get all types. See update.

Comment: This is still a rather limited variety - You may be able to produce "thickened lines" but not a general "thickened tree", for example.

Answer (score 8):

From V12, there is an inbuilt function [RandomPolygon](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPolygon.html)

`RandomPolygon[7]` returns a simple polygon with seven sides. Other types are `"Convex"`, `"StarShaped"`.

```
Table[Graphics[p, ImageSize -> 100], {p, RandomPolygon[{"Simple", 5}, 3]}],
Table[Graphics[p, ImageSize -> 100], {p, RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 5}, 3]}],
Table[Graphics[p, ImageSize -> 100], {p, RandomPolygon[{"StarShaped"}, 3]}]}]
```

[image]

In general `RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 5}, 3, DataRange -> {{1,2}, {3,4}}]` would give you 3 random pentagon within the rectangular box (1,3) to (2,4).