# How to draw the area that cover given points on listplot

Tags: plotting

I have a lot of points' coordinates. I drew them on a 2d plot with `ListPlot`, and the points cover an area. Then I need to get the region that cover these points. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You mean the minimum-area convex region that includes all the points.  (This is the `ConvexHull`.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you are asking about convex region. Without this statement one can draw very weird region:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
Show[Graphics@{LightBlue, EdgeForm@Lighter@Blue, 
   Polygon@Deintersect[pts]}, ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image]

`Deintersect` is defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32785/4678).

Answer (score 2):

[`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) :

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];

Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image]

For earlier versions see [`ConvexHull`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputationalGeometry/ref/ConvexHull.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another area defined by the list of points:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
Graphics[{Blue, Point @ pts,
  LightBlue, EdgeForm @ Gray, Polygon @ pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]]}]
```

[image]