# ListPlot join points by nearest neighbor rather than order

Tags: plotting, order

I have found some software that allows me to "data mine" the values from publication figures. I have a bunch of contours from papers that I've mined using this software, and am having some trouble plotting the points with the Joined command.

Unfortunately, the downloaded points are sorted by increasing x values, which makes the plotting of Gaussian-esque contours very difficult. I've searched around the forums and haven't found anyone mentioning this problem.

Here's an example on a very small, simpler distribution (note my other sets are much larger so brute force definitely won't work.)

```
data={{62.0774, 0.598737}, {62.2377, 0.619119}, {62.4048, 
0.580509}, {62.5466, 0.637818}, {62.9276, 0.654518}, {62.9668, 
      0.566973}, {63.3095, 0.671261}, {63.8137, 0.688518}, {63.8913, 
      0.565805}, {64.4067, 0.703821}, {64.8157, 0.568541}, {65.1005, 
      0.718671}, {65.7401, 0.573603}, {65.9282, 0.732056}, {66.6646, 
      0.580678}, {66.7973, 0.743456}, {67.6058, 0.589303}, {67.7571, 
      0.755602}, {68.5512, 0.599853}, {68.6815, 0.761419}, {69.4, 
      0.614478}, {69.6059, 0.76384}, {70.1679, 0.631668}, {70.5117, 
      0.759937}, {70.5514, 0.759266}, {70.7216, 0.649606}, {71.3609, 
      0.666955}, {71.3764, 0.751005}, {71.7909, 0.736308}, {71.8078, 
      0.687055}, {71.947, 0.702022}, {72.0491, 0.717738}}
```

Using `ListPlot` gives me this:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: points]

While using `ListLinePlot` gives me this

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: lines]

because the points are ordered with increasing x-value.

So, is there any way to either join the points by nearest neighbor, or re-order the list such that the joined command will give me a neat line? This seems like a traveling-salesman type problem, which could quickly get slow as I increase the number of points too much.

Comment: Try `FindShortestTour`

Comment: Try something like `ListLinePlot[data[[Last@FindShortestTour@data]]]`  but it is not perfect

Comment: Will your data always be in convex hulls?

Comment: @MikeY unfortunately not! They are the results of a Bayesian analysis and many have differing, strange, and non-analytical forms.

Comment: Related: [(136181)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136181/121)

Comment: One thing to note. If your distributions are going to be in extremely abstract forms, it could be more beneficial to not connect-the-dots. If this is for presentation, the human mind is really great at inferring shapes from just points. Maybe consider just using ListPlot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath) to reorder your data. However, [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath) expects the scale of the two coordinates to be close, so you need to rescale first:

```
new = FindCurvePath[data . {{1, 0}, {0, 100}}]
ListLinePlot[data[[#]]& /@ new]
```

> {{2, 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 29, 
>     28, 25, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2}}

[image]

**Update**

Roman suggested automating the scaling of the data. Here is one possibility for rescaling the data:

```
rescale = RescalingTransform[CoordinateBounds[data]] @ data;
```

Then, using `FindCurvePath` on the rescaled data:

```
new = FindCurvePath @ rescale
```

> {{2, 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 29, 28, 25, 
>     24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2}}

produces the same result.

Comment: Why not just the closely related `ListCurvePathPlot`?

Comment: @Roman Did you try using `ListCurvePathPlot`? Because the data has such a small variation in the `y` coordinate, `ListCurvePathPlot` doesn't work well. That's why I scaled the data and used `FindCurvePath` to reorder the data, and then plotted the reordered data.

Comment: Ah yes, brilliant! Maybe even easier for automation would be a hands-free rescaling by the covariance matrix of the data, something like `path = First[FindCurvePath[data.(Transpose[#[[2]]]/Sqrt[#[[1]]] &@ Eigensystem[Covariance[data]])]]`, which tries to map the given data onto a unit circle before applying `FindCurvePath`. What do you think?

Comment: @Roman Adding automatic rescaling is a good idea. I added a simple version based on `RescalingTransform`. You can add an answer using `Eigensystem`/`Covariance` if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your multiple solutions @CarlWoll! These worked perfectly for all my datasets other than the ones with kinks, those of which I can manually edit.

Answer (score 10):

Since your data can form a star convex polygon, we can sort by the angle with respect to a certain point:

```
center = Mean[data];
ListLinePlot[ArrayPad[SortBy[data, ArcTan @@ (# - center) &], {{0, 1}}, "Periodic"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

By scaling the data into the covariance ellipsoid, we can achieve hands-free auto-scaling before calculating a `FindCurvePath` along @CarlWoll 's solution:

```
path = First@FindCurvePath[
  data.Transpose[#[[2]]/Sqrt[#[[1]]]&@Eigensystem[Covariance[data]]]]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 29, 28, 25, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2}

```
ListPlot[data[[path]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if the data points are meant to describe a closed loop, the path can be found with

```
path = Last@FindShortestTour[
  data.Transpose[#[[2]]/Sqrt[#[[1]]]&@Eigensystem[Covariance[data]]]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 25, 28, 29, 32, 31, 30, 27, 26, 23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 6, 3, 1}

The transformed data that are fed into `FindCurvePath` or `FindShortestTour` have a unit covariance matrix, which makes it easier to find a good path:

```
Sdata = data.Transpose[#[[2]]/Sqrt[#[[1]]]&@Eigensystem[Covariance[data]]];
Chop@Covariance[Sdata]
```

> {{1., 0}, {0, 1.}}

We can see that these scaled points nearly lie on a circle:

```
ListPlot[Sdata, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing the plot command for your first image and the command shown for it should be with the second image.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon , for some reason the formatting got scrambled when I added the second image.

Comment: Thank you for this solution @Roman! It also works excellently.

Answer (score 4):

Sorta lame, but rescaling and `Nearest` can be used to get triples, with `Line` to connect the triples (each has a point and its two closest neighbors which in this case will do what you want).

```
data2 = Map[{1, 100}*# &, data];
nf = Nearest[data2];
triples0 = Map[RotateRight, nf[data2, 3]];
triples = Map[Line, Map[{1, 1/100}*# &, triples0, {2}]];

Show[{ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Black &)], 
  Graphics[{Green, triples}]}]
```

[image]