# Convert image of roads to 3D graphics

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing

I have images like this:

[image]

and I want to convert those lines to 3D graphics so I can export it as OBJ or STL.

My best attempt has been by using MorphologicalGraph ([following this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4197/how-to-convert-a-2d-image-into-a-3d-graphics)) and doing:

```
img=Import["map.png"]

g=MorphologicalGraph[MorphologicalBinarize[img],VertexCoordinates->Automatic,EdgeWeight->Automatic];

edges = EdgeList[g];    
vertices = Thread[Rule[VertexList[g], PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]]];

lines = ((edges/.vertices)/.UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> Line[{a, b}]);

lines3D = {Append[#[[1, 1]], 0], Append[#[[1, 2]], 0]} & /@ lines;

Graphics3D[Line /@ lines3D]
```

I do get a Graphics3D but it looks like this:

[image]

which is very different from the original image and, actually, if I export that to OBJ or STL, it doesn't work (3D viewers say the file is wrong). I got it working by using thin tubes, e.g.

```
Graphics3D[Tube[#,0.5]&/@(lines/. {x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>{x,0,y})]
```

[image]

In any case, I'm not getting what I want. I know there are programs like AutoCAD Raster Design that should be able to do this, but I want to do it with Wolfram Language.

Any ideas on how to preserve the original image and get it in 3D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWJe.png"];
mesh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]];
reg = RegionProduct[mesh, Line[{{0.}, {1.}}]]

Export["test.stl", reg]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With little help `ListCurvePathPlot` allows obtaining a nice-looking and very efficient vector representation:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWJe.png"];
mc = MorphologicalComponents[img];
imgSize = ImageDimensions[img];
gr = ListCurvePathPlot[
  Table[Replace[
    Position[mc, i], {i_, j_} :> {j, imgSize[[2]] - i + 1}, {-2}], {i, Max[mc]}],
  PlotRange -> Transpose[{{1, 1}, imgSize}], ImageSize -> imgSize, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[JoinForm[{"Miter", 1}], Thickness[1/imgSize[[1]]]], 
  Axes -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity, AspectRatio -> Automatic]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {79.9067, Null}
> ```

```
gr
```

> [image: output]

```
Graphics3D[gr[[1, 1, 1]] /. {Line[pts_] :> Line[Join[pts, Table[{0.}, Length[pts]], 2]],
    Annotation -> (# &), Directive -> Sequence}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image: output]

```
Graphics3D[gr[[1, 1, 1]] /. {Line[pts_] :> Line[Join[pts, Table[{0.}, Length[pts]], 2]],
    Annotation -> (# &), Directive -> Sequence, _Hue -> Black}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image: output]

---

`ListCurvePathPlot` also can work with the points directly, without the preprocessing by `MorphologicalComponents`. It takes much longer and the result differs:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWJe.png"]
imgSize = ImageDimensions[img];
gr0 = ListCurvePathPlot[PixelValuePositions[img, 1], 
    PlotRange -> Transpose[{{1, 1}, imgSize}], ImageSize -> imgSize, 
    PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[JoinForm[{"Miter", 1}], Thickness[1/imgSize[[1]]], Black], 
    Axes -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
gr0
```

> ```
> {707.343, Null}
> ```

> [image: output]

---

Another way is to use fast and exact vectorization approach based on the code from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195259/280) answer:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWJe.png"];
pxls = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
segments = Line[Nearest[pxls, pxls, {2, Sqrt[2]}]];
Graphics3D[{JoinForm[{"Miter", 1}], 
  Thickness[1/ImageDimensions[img][[1]]], 
  Replace[segments, {i_, j_} :> {i, j, 0}, {-2}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image: output]

(here I converted the binary image into a collection of two-point line segments).