# How to find each internal angles of an n-sided irregular polygon

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework, polygons, polyhedra

The vectors given in problem are:

```
p1 = {1, 2, 2}; 
p2 = {3, 1, 1/4}; 
p3 = {2, 3, 9/4}; 
p4 = {5, 2, 0}; 
p5 = {3/2, 5/4, 19/16};
```

Find all 5 of the (internal) angles of S. Note that the internal angles of an n-sided polygon always add up to . Give the angles in degrees in numerical value.

I tried `VectorAngle[p3 - p1, p5 - p1] 3*Pi // N` I don't think the answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
p1 = {1, 2, 2};
p2 = {3, 1, 1/4};
p3 = {2, 3, 9/4};
p4 = {5, 2, 0};
p5 = {3/2, 5/4, 19/16};
pts = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}
chReg = ConvexHullRegion[pts]
```

---

```
angs = PolygonAngle[chReg]*180/\[Pi] // N
```

> ```
> {104.946, 105.07, 141.61, 137.942, 50.4316}
> ```

```
Total[angs]
```

> ```
> 540.
> ```

---

Visualization:

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[Black]
  , Black
  , Line@pts
  , AbsolutePointSize[10]
  , Red, Point@pts
  , LightRed, chReg
  }
 , Boxed -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is an extended comment, because I am a bit confused.

In the OP the following is given:

```
p1 = {1, 2, 2};
p2 = {3, 1, 1/4};
p3 = {2, 3, 9/4};
p4 = {5, 2, 0};
p5 = {3/2, 5/4, 19/16};
```

from which we can create a [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)

```
poly = Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}];

Graphics3D[poly]
```

> [image: polygon]

From the above picture, I count $9$ internal angles. Based on this [`table`](https://byjus.com/maths/interior-angles-of-a-polygon/#Sum%20of%20interior%20angles) the sum of angles of the Nonagon is equal to $1260$. Which can be easily derived using [`PolygonAngle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolygonAngle.html) in the following manner:

```
FullSimplify@Total@PolygonAngle[poly] /. Pi -> 180 Degree
```

> [image: totalangles]

Comment: It is strange that `SimplePolygonQ@poly` returns `True` because `poly` is a self-intersecting polygon: `Graphics3D[{poly, Red, Sphere[#, .1] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}}]`.

Comment: A proof: `{RegionIntersection[Line[{p1, p2}], Line[{p4, p5}]], 
 RegionIntersection[Line[{p2, p3}], Line[{p4, p5}]]}`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks for bringing this up. I did not check it myself. That's strange indeed.

Comment: Wolfram support confirmed that it is a known bug in `SimplePolygonQ` ([CASE:4930736]).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov many thanks again for this. Do you want to write an answer? Should I just update the existing answer? Nothing is required? Not sure to be honest

Comment: The OP's question isn't well-posed because it doesn't make it clear which polygon is under consideration. You can simply update your answer with this information. It is also interesting that `PolygonAngle` seemingly is able to handle self-intersection polygons in a special way (but I didn't check the correctness and how it does it). Or you may do nothing unless the OP updates the question.